# Globally asymptotic stable gradient system has unstable point

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, vector-analysis, stability-in-odes, gradient-flows

Given a gradient system

$$\frac{d\theta_1}{dt}=-\sin(\theta_1-\theta_2)$$
$$\frac{d\theta_2}{dt}=-\sin(\theta_2-\theta_1)$$

The system is a gradient system since

$$\frac{d\vec \theta}{dt}=-\nabla V(\vec\theta) = -\nabla(1-\cos(\theta_1-\theta_2))$$

Since the system is invariant by replacing all $\theta_i$ to $\theta_i+\alpha$, this will leads to a continuum of equilibria. To remove this freedom, we fix $\theta_1=0$, then the system becomes
$$\frac{d\theta_2}{dt}=-\sin(\theta_2)$$

It has two equilibrium points $\theta_2=0$ and $\theta_2=\pi$.

The energy function is $V(\theta_2)=-\cos(\theta_2)+1.$

The second derivative of $V(\theta_2)$ is $\cos\theta_2$.

1. Since the second derivative is negative on $\theta_2=\pi$, it is an unstable equilibrium point.
2. Since the second derivative is positive $\theta_2=0$, it is a locally asymptotically stable (LAS) equilibrium point.
3. Since this is a gradient system, only $\theta_2=0$ is locally asymptotically stable, then it is globally asymptotically stable (GAS).

But it is a little counterintuitive in the sense of convexity of energy function: how comes that the energy function is concave on $\theta_2=\pi$, and $\theta_2=0$ is globally asymptotically stable?

For example, let say the figure of an energy function looks like the following

[image]

and it is convex on the local minimum, and concave on the local maximum. How come all trajectories will converge to the local minimum?

As illustrated in the figure, trajectories starting from the part behind the local maximum cannot converge to the local minimum.

Comment: This is very unclear. What is your problem here? The gradient is defined to be converging to a local minimum or more generally to a point where the gradient is zero. If sufficiently close to the global minimum, it will converge to it. Finally, your system has more than four equilibrium points, it has in fact a continuum of equilibrium point $\theta_1=\theta_2$.

Comment: @KBS I think global stable equilibrium point of the system is different from global minimum of $f(x)$. By verifying the second derivative of $f(x)$, we obtain the local stability of the 4 equilibrium points, which gives that only $(0,0)$ is locally asymptotically stable. Since the system is a gradient system, and only $(0,0)$ is stable and all others are unstable, we can conclude that $(0,0)$ is globally asymptotically stable. This is from the perspective of stability theory.

Comment: We know that all trajectories will eventually converge to $(0,0)$ by the above stability analysis. But, if we rethink about this fact from perspective of the energy function $f(x)$, it seems not possible that all trajectories will converge to $(0,0)$: since some trajectories will be blocked from converge to it by the concave property of the other state (trajectories near the other state have to climb up to the hill and then downhill, and then converge to $(0,0)$.

Comment: Read again what I wrote and also try to understand what a gradient system is and how it evolves on the manifold described by the energy function. Moreover, it is not because one equilibrium is stable and the other unstable, that the stable one is globally stable. You need to spend more time on the analysis of Dynamical Systems. That may be true for certain classes of gradient systems but not for dynamical systems in general.

Comment: I just re-edit the description by fixing $\theta_1=0$ to avoid a continuum of equilibria.

Comment: $\theta_1$ is a state that evolves over time, you cannot just set it to the value you want.

Comment: I just did some simulations and $(0,0)$ is not globally stable as I said. If the difference between the initial value for the state is small enough, both states will converge to the same value which is the average of the initial conditions. That can be proven by linearization. Your whole reasoning is incorrect.

Comment: @KBS The system is invariant by replacing all $\theta_i$ to $\theta_i+\alpha$. Thus the rotational symmetry leads to a continuum of equilibria. Setting $\theta_1=0$ is to remove this freedom.

Comment: I am sorry but you do not decide what the state at equilibrium will be. If you pick $(0,2)$ as initial condition, the state will converge to (1,1).

Comment: @KBS Situation changes by letting $\theta_1=0$. For this new system, it is globally stable at $\theta_2=0$.

Comment: Note that this is exactly solvable: if the state starts in $\theta_1 = \theta^* + \delta$, $\theta_2 = \theta^*-\delta$, the exact solution is $\theta^* \pm \tan^{-1}(e^{-2t}\tan\delta)$.

Comment: @KBS About 'Since all other equilibrium points are unstable, the only stable equilibrium point becomes globally stable.': this can be deduced by the fact that all attractors of gradient systems are fixed points, i.e. trajectories will all converge to a fixed point. In other words, we do not need to bother by other kinds of attractors such as limit cycles and so on. 

Since all other equilibrium points are unstable, all trajectories will converge to the only stable equilibrium point, thus it is globally asymptotically stable.

Comment: @HJ_dynamics What about this system then? You have a continuum of stable equilibrium points... And do not tell me that you set $\theta_1=0$ because you do not get to choose where the system ends up. The game to pick an initial condition and see where the system goes.

Comment: @KBS About this system (without letting $\theta_1=0$), it has a continuum of locally stable equilibrium points $\theta_1=\theta_2$. Other continuum of equilibria $\theta_1=\theta_2+\pi$ and $\theta_1=\theta_2-\pi$ are unstable. Trajectories will eventually converge to one of points lies on $\theta_1=\theta_2$. I don't see any contradiction.. Where arises a contradiction?

Answer (score 1):

As $\dot θ_1+\dot θ_2=0$, the sum is constant and one can replace $θ_2=c-θ_1$ to get a single equation
$$
\dot θ_1=-\sin(2θ_1-c)
$$
This has indeed a stable equilibrium at $2θ_1-c=0$ and unstable equilibria at $2θ_1-c=\pm\pi$, continued with period $2\pi$ on the right side, thus period $\pi$ in $θ_1$.